# Is there any reason I should not be able to recharacterize Excess Roth IRA contributions to avoid the 6% tax hit?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, ira, roth-ira

I contributed 6k to a roth IRA early last year for 2021. I later got married and am now over the income threshold entirely.

I'm under the impression that the best option to avoid losses is to recharacterize the contribution to a traditional ira. merrill lynch is telling me I need to withdraw it, which looks like it will cost 15% (10 federal, 5 state).

Is there any reason I should not be able to recharacterize to avoid the 6% tax hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excess contribution withdrawal doesn't have any tax penalty (you need to add the earnings to your taxable income though).

However you're right, you don't have to withdraw and can [recharacterize](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/retirement-plans-faqs-regarding-iras#Recharacterization%20of%20IRA%20Contributions) instead. It has to be done by tax due date (including extensions, which is up to October 15th), and it usually takes awhile for the custodians to process.

> If this is done by the due date for filing your tax return (including extensions), you can treat the contribution as made to the second IRA for that year (effectively ignoring the contribution to the first IRA).

Comment: Should I assume that any gains in the account since the contribution should be allocated between the 6k contribution and the earnings? So I withdraw 6k + earnings * (6k / balance_after_contribution) and report the latter part of that as income?

Comment: @roth__frustrations that's right, and the custodians are supposed to do the math for you.

Comment: ... and that's probably why they didn't offer it; it's a pain for them (but they are legally required to do, it)